# How to obtain result as array of Hashes in Ruby (mysql2 gem)

Tags: mysql, ruby, mysql2

I'm using Ruby's mysql2 gem found here:
https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2

I have the following code:

```
client = Mysql2::Client.new(
  :host => dbhost, 
  :port => dbport, :database => dbname,
  :username => dbuser, 
  :password => dbpass)
sql = "SELECT column1, column2, column3 FROM table WHERE id=#{id}"
res = client.query(sql, :as => :array)
p res # prints #<Mysql2::Result:0x007fa8e514b7d0>
```

Is it possible the above `.query` call to return array of hashes, each hesh in the `res` array to be in the format `column => value`. I can do this manually but from the docs I was left with the impression that I can get the results directly loaded in memory in the mentioned format. I need this, because after that I have to encode the result in json anyway, so there is no advantage for me to fetch the rows one by one. Also the amount of data is always very small.

Comment: FYI: If you happen to be using rails, you can use `Rails.configuration.database_configuration[Rails.env]` in place of the parameters hash for `new`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change

```
res = client.query(sql, :as => :array)
```

to:

```
res = client.query(sql, :as => :hash)
```

As @Tadman says, `:as => :hash` is the default, so actually you don't have to specify anything.

Comment: Has the default changed?  Seems like the default is `:array` in `0.3.13`

Answer (score 3):

You can always fetch the results as JSON directly:

```
res = client.query(sql, :as => :json)
```

The default format, as far as I know, is an array of hashes. If you want symbol keys you need to ask for those. A lot of this is [documented](https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2) in the gem itself.

You should also be *extremely* cautious about inserting things into your query with string substitution. Whenever possible, use placeholders. These aren't supported by the `mysql2` driver directly, so you should use an adapter layer like ActiveRecord or [Sequel](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/).

Comment: `client.query(sql, :as => :json)` and `client.query(sql, :as => :array)` return Mysql2::Result object, not array of hashes or json. Also I'm left with the impression that `:as => :json` is not implemented.

Comment: It is. You just need to ask the result for what you want. Try `result.to_s` or `result.to_a`.

Comment: `(:as => :json).to_s` still returns `Mysql2::Result object`, `:as => :hash` solved it. Thanks for the ideas

Answer (score 3):

The [source code](https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2/blob/0.3.16/lib/mysql2/result.rb) for mysql2 implemented MySql2::Result to simply `include Enumerable`, so the obvious way to access the data is by using any method implemented in `Enumerable`[doc here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html).

For example, #each, #each_with_index, #collect and #to_a are all useful ways to access the `Result`'s elements.

```
puts res.collect{ |row| "Then the next result was #{row}" }.join("\t")
```